# Keikai: how to check if filter is enabled

Tags: spreadsheet

I am trying to import an Excel file that has filter into Keikai Spreadsheet for further integration. I need to know programmatically if the filter in the sheet is enabled or not, and its range. What is the right API to use? Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
spreadsheet.getWorksheet().isAutoFilterEnabled();
spreadsheet.getWorksheet().getAutoFilterRange();
```

Please refer to https://keikai.io/javadoc/latest/io/keikai/client/api/Worksheet.html